# Django inlineformset_factory not saving or editing modelform with choices

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use an inline formset to create company open and close hours i.e Monday to Friday with different open and close times for each day.

The company profile form is a regular modelform.
The company hours i load below it is a modelformset with id passed from company profile form.

The modelform and the modelformset load fine to create.
The modelform loads with pre-selected values on edit but not modelformset.
I don't know if i am saving anything on create because i get an empty modelformset when i try to edit the instance.

What should i change here to make sure that the modelformset saves selected choices or loads pre-selected choices on edit?

```
def addprofile(request):
current_user = request.user
company = Company() ##To create new instance
#company = Company.objects.get(id= request.session['my_ids']) ## To get old instance
OpeningHourslineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Company, OpeningHours, form=OpeningHoursForm, extra=7 )##fields=("weekday", "fromHour","fromMinute", "toHour", "toMinute")
if request.session['entry_count'] > 1:
    messages.success( request, 'You can only create two business profiles now' )
    return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('home') )
else:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hourformset = OpeningHourslineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=company)
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
        ###### deal with hourformset here
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.pub_date= timezone.now()
            model_instance.user= current_user.id
            model_instance.save()
        else:
            print("companyform not saved")
            ###################
        if hourformset.is_valid():
            hourformset.save(commit=False)
            for product in hourformset:
                if product.is_valid():
                    product.save(commit=False) 
                    product.company = model_instance.id
                    product.save()

            instances = hourformset.save()
        else:
            print(" modelform not saved")


        return HttpResponseRedirect('/bizprofile/success')

    else:
        hourformset = OpeningHourslineFormSet(instance=company)
        form = CompanyForm()
    context = {'hourformset': hourformset, 'form': form}
    return render_to_response('bizprofile/addprofile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give formset a queryset in order to show your saved instances:

```
# hours is a queryset that you got from company, pseudo code here
hours = company.hours.all()
hourformset = OpeningHourslineFormSet(request.POST,
                                      request.FILES,
                                      queryset=hours)
```

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset).

Comment: Still loading an empty modelformset.  Do i need to do anything special to save selected choices ?  I am thinking i am not saving a thing.

Comment: Or would you be kinder and actually show me a minimal example of a modelformset with choices being saved and edited. I think that would be enough for me.

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious in your view, although you have some redundant `save()` called. Can you do a query in the shell to see if your formset saves anything?

Comment: Well actually, I don't think this is right: `product.company = model_instance.id`, try `product.company = model_instance`. Also don't call this: `hourformset.save(commit=False)` and `instances = hourformset.save()`, it's not helping anything, because you have already saving individual forms.

Comment: Like i suspected, i am not saving anything on the hours table. Currently i have 0 rows on hours table and 1 row on company table.

Comment: You might also have `hourformset.is_valid()` is false because your formset is not valid. Try to print the errors.

Comment: I will work on this later. This part alone has taken me four hours. I have tried print (hourformset.errors) on views but  it seems to be valid. Worst case scenario is that i use 7 different modelforms for each day.

Comment: One last thing is to print `new_product` after change your code to `new_product = product.save()` to see if product is saved or not. I think it's close.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on this link:

[Django modelform not saving input choices and not returning errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829908/django-modelform-not-saving-input-choices-and-not-returning-errors?noredirect=1#comment55426466_33829908)

Problem arose from saving different data types to different model field types.