# Django modelform not saving input choices and not returning errors

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a modelform that only works(saves input data to database) if none of the fields has choices. When i introduce choices, i don't get any errors and the form seems to be valid but nothing gets saved.
I have combed through the documentation and i am not returning anything useful.

I am convinced that i need to do more in my views to get the selected input choices or i need to add a few methods to the model class. Please point me in the right direction.

Here is my model:

```
class OpeningHours(models.Model):
'''
'''
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Opening Hour'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Opening Hours'
    #######################################################
    mytime = Bizhours()
    ################################################ 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company =models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=mytime.getweekdays(), default='Monday', null=True)
    fromHour = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    fromMinute = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    toHour = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    toMinute = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    '''
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    weekday = models.IntegerField(choices=mytime.getweekdays())
    fromHour = models.TimeField(choices=mytime.gettime12())
    fromMinute = models.TimeField(choices=mytime.getminutes())
    toHour = models.TimeField(choices=mytime.gettime12())
    toMinute = models.TimeField(choices=mytime.getminutes())
    '''


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s (%s - %s)" % (self.company, self.weekday, self.fromHour, self.toHour)
```

here is my views

```
@login_required
def addprofile(request):
current_user = request.user
#OpeningHoursFormSet = modelformset_factory(OpeningHours, form=OpeningHoursForm,extra=1)

if request.session['entry_count'] > 1:
    messages.success( request, 'You can only create two business profiles now' )
    return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('home') )
else:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OpeningHoursForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.company ="thiscompany"
            model_instance.weekday = request.POST.get('weekday') 
            model_instance.save()
        else:
            print("problems saving edited form")

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/bizprofile/success')
    else: 
        form = OpeningHoursForm() 
        context = {'form': form}    
    return render_to_response('bizprofile/addprofile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here is the form

```
{% extends "bizprofile/bizprofilebase.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.subject.errors %}
<ol>
{% for error in form.subject.errors %}
    <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endif %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.get_username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>

    <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{form}}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>

{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: And where is your form?

Comment: This was part of a modelformset but i have scaled it down to this. I am now sure that it is the choices because without them i can see saved data in database.

Comment: What does your `get_week_day()` function returns?

Comment: def getweekdays(self):  
        self.WEEKDAYS = [ 
                    (1, _("Monday")), 
                    (2, _("Tuesday")),
                    (3, _("Wednesday")),
                    (4, _("Thursday")),
                    (5, _("Friday")),
                    (6, _("Saturday")),
                    (7, _("Sunday")),
                    ]
        return self.WEEKDAYS

Comment: It returns a list of weekdays.

Comment: Then you can't say `default="Monday"`. In choices the second item in each tuple is the display value, the first value is the one that will be stored in database. You might try `default=1`.

Comment: Also, you should either set a breakpoint or at least print the value you got from `request.POST` to see if the data looks right. It's a common debug technique.

Comment: I actually don't need a default value. I was just trying that to see. I changed that-- i can see the choices (monday to friday) but nothing gets saved.

Comment: If you print `request.POST.get('weekday')` before you assign it to `model_instance`, what's the value? Also you are using `CharField` for `weekday` but your choices are integers 1~7. You should change it to `IntegerField`.

Comment: Finally, everything works now. @Shang Wang, you are a gentle person and a hero. That was my problem all along.

Comment: @Shang Wang, please put that into an answer and i will accept it as answered

Comment: No problem, glad that I can help, you can close the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that OP is using `CharField` for weekday data type, but the choices returned from a function are defined as integers. Since they are not compatible, the data could not be saved.